# Apache Nutch build with Apache Ant failed

Tags: java, apache, ant, nutch

I am trying build the Nutch project by Ant. I go to the Nutch directory where looks like this:

[image: Nutch Directory]

Then I open the terminal here and run command bellow:

```
mahdi@mahdi-SVT13136CXS:/opt/apache-nutch-1.5-source$ sudo ant
[sudo] password for mahdi: 
Buildfile: /opt/apache-nutch-1.5-source/build.xml
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml. It could not be found.

ivy-probe-antlib:

ivy-download:
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml. It could not be found.

-ivy-download-unchecked:

ivy-init-antlib:

ivy-init:

init:

BUILD FAILED
/opt/apache-nutch-1.5-source/build.xml:71: Unparseable date: "01/25/1971 2:00 pm"

Total time: 0 seconds
```

And this too:

```
mahdi@mahdi-SVT13136CXS:/opt/apache-nutch-1.5-source$ sudo ant runtime
Buildfile: /opt/apache-nutch-1.5-source/build.xml
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml. It could not be found.

ivy-probe-antlib:

ivy-download:
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml. It could not be found.

-ivy-download-unchecked:

ivy-init-antlib:

ivy-init:

init:

BUILD FAILED
/opt/apache-nutch-1.5-source/build.xml:71: Unparseable date: "01/25/1971 2:00 pm"

Total time: 0 seconds
```

And either this one:

```
mahdi@mahdi-SVT13136CXS:/opt/apache-nutch-1.5-source$ sudo ant clean deploy
Buildfile: /opt/apache-nutch-1.5-source/build.xml
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml. It could not be found.

clean-build:
   [delete] Deleting directory /opt/apache-nutch-1.5-source/build

clean-lib:

clean-dist:

clean-runtime:

clean:

ivy-probe-antlib:

ivy-download:
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml. It could not be found.

-ivy-download-unchecked:

ivy-init-antlib:

ivy-init:

init:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /opt/apache-nutch-1.5-source/build
    [mkdir] Created dir: /opt/apache-nutch-1.5-source/build/classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: /opt/apache-nutch-1.5-source/build/release
    [mkdir] Created dir: /opt/apache-nutch-1.5-source/build/test
    [mkdir] Created dir: /opt/apache-nutch-1.5-source/build/test/classes

BUILD FAILED
/opt/apache-nutch-1.5-source/build.xml:71: Unparseable date: "01/25/1971 2:00 pm"

Total time: 0 seconds
```

But as you see each one tells errors. I created a fresh java project with netbeans and tried to build that just by running "ant" and every thing went good.

As additional info:

```
mahdi@mahdi-SVT13136CXS:/opt/apache-nutch-1.5-source$ java -version
openjdk version "9-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode)
```

And:

```
mahdi@mahdi-SVT13136CXS:/opt/apache-nutch-1.5-source$ ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on July 8 2015
```

Comment: Would you mind showing the build script around error?

Comment: The error message
 `/opt/apache-nutch-1.5-source/build.xml:71: Unparseable date: "01/25/1971 2:00 pm"`
ev. points to a localization problem: it's an English (US) date format which fails to parse. Could you
(a) add the output of `locale` from the terminal where Nutch fails to compile and (b) try to remove the touch command from build.xml - Thanks

Comment: @SebastianNagel I think you may be right. (a) what do you mean by "where nutch fails"? you mean I run the locale command after nutch failed? (b) Isn't it necessary? what about other time parsings? - Thanks - TG

Comment: Regarding (a): it doesn't matter whether before or after, the output may help to reproduce the problem.
Reg. (b): touching the template configuration files using a date in the past makes sure that modified configuration files are not overwritten ("re-instantiated") from the templates. But this may only happen when the source tree from the version control is compiled. The source packages do not contain configuration templates.

Comment: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=fa_IR
LC_TIME=fa_IR
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=fa_IR
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=fa_IR
LC_NAME=fa_IR
LC_ADDRESS=fa_IR
LC_TELEPHONE=fa_IR
LC_MEASUREMENT=fa_IR
LC_IDENTIFICATION=fa_IR
LC_ALL=
 //this is the result of running "locale" command. Is that ok???

Comment: Thanks, a Farsi locale could explain why parsing an English data fails. However, I'm not able to reproduce the problem after having changed the locale to fa_IR.